# Reading .xlsx in java

Tags: java, excel, eclipse, xlsx

I've read every single question here and couldn't find the easy answer.

What I need is just 1 .jar, which I will add into my project in Eclipse. Then I just want to import it and use a library that can extract data from .xlsx file.

Apache POI needs a lot of .jar files. It crashes and throws a lot of exceptions that don't make sense.

Smartxlsx has absolutely no documentation and it's horribly hard to use/understand it.

Comment: Use the Apache POI stuff. It works. That it needs more than one jar file is a complete non-issue.

Comment: use gradle or maven if you want to manage your dependencies better

Comment: If you encounter exceptions, you can ask about them here.

Comment: Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/apache/commons/collections4/ListValuedMap - and in this line I have XSSFWorkbook myWorkBook = new XSSFWorkbook (fis);

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I believe that Apache POI would be one of best solutions to read XLSX files.

It's only required two dependencies(As you mentioned it doesn't required lot of jars) and if you interested please go through [following example](http://nirmalbalasooriya.blogspot.sg/2016/11/read-excel-file-from-apache-poi-xls-or.html) where you can get some idea about how to integrate Apache POI with in couple of minutes.